# Best Linux distributions?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice

I wanted to know the best Linux distributions for beginners? And also how I will go about installing it too.

Comment: Please read the Help section, notably [what type of questions should I avoid asking?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Subjective questions that just solicit opinion, as yours does, are not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Your question is somewhat vague. Please could you tell us, where are you going to install Linux, for what, etc? Meanwhile take a look at [DistroWatch](http://www.distrowatch.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question will be very hard to answer because you did not give any criteria except for mentioning that you are a beginner to the *nix.  Given only that fact, I would recommend the [desktop version of Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop)). There are a **lot** of popular distributions out there, and they all have pros and cons.  I will give you some of the pros of Ubuntu:

- Easy to download and install.  Just download the image from the site.  You will end up with an .iso file or similar.  This is an image that you will have to burn onto a DVD or use to install a VM if that's the route you go.  Just burn the file to a DVD (as an image disk, not a data disk), pop it into a DVD drive, and follow the prompts.  Most Linux installations are similar (I know at least Ubuntu, RHEL, Centos, Fedora, and Debian offer similar from direct experience).  However, Canonical (the owners of Ubuntu) have really marketed Ubuntu towards the casual user, and have really gone out of their way to make it easy for users learning Linux for the first time.  Once you know a bit more about the underlying Debian architecture, you can make decisions from there.
- Easy for new Linux users to install and navigate in a basic way.
- It comes with a "store", reminiscent of the Apple Store, which will help you discover, download, and install software slightly easier than most other distributions.
- There is a lot of beginner's support for Ubuntu.
- If you really get into it, Ubuntu is a good stepping-stone to a more specialized distribution of Linux.
- Free for personal use (although most are).

My opinion, go to Ubuntu's site and follow their dead-simple installation instructions.  Otherwise, read one of the many articles comparing Linux distributions for beginners, here are three I just found on my phone:

https://www.linux.com/news/software/applications/775873-the-best-linux-distribution-for-new-users

http://www.pcworld.com/article/2947333/operating-systems/the-best-linux-distributions-for-beginners.html

http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/which-is-the-best-distro-for-beginners--1213490

Comment: The beginner's support is a two edged sword, there are also very many beginners with trivial questions.